# Разрешить писать на Мете при первичной блокировке участника

Tags: предложение, привилегии, блокировка

По-моему, уже не первый раз случается ситуация, когда забаненные участники создают себе дубля дабы как-то попробовать "восстановить справедливость" или "излить душу". При этом из-за минимального порога в 5 баллов, новый аккаунт не может писать на Мету, и создаёт вопрос на основном сайте.

Налицо появление при этом мусорных данных:

- новый аккаунт, который больше не будет использован. А если и будет, то его следует объединить (модератору) с исходным аккаунтом или тоже предать бану;
- вопрос, созданный на основном сайте, который нужно переносить, опять таки, модератору;
- даже после переноса вопрос остается висеть там, где он был изначально задан, пока не будет заминусован и не станет доступен только избранным.

Поэтому, предложение: дать забаненному участнику право "последнего слова" - создать вопрос на Мете, написать в чате, позвонить другу ... Короче говоря, попробовать создать такие условия, чтобы избежать появления, описанных выше, мусорных данных.

Comment: Тогда надо разделять бан на основном сайте и бан на мете.

Comment: @Nofate это уже детали реализации.

Comment: Есть и обратная сторона: все ругательства, которые сейчас адресуются модератору, будут выставляться на обозрение всего сообщества.

Comment: @NickVolynkin так создание дубля всё равно этому не препятствует.

Comment: @NickVolynkin а что, есть какой-то механизм, позволяющий приватно обругать модератора при бане? Насколько я вижу, все ругательства, адресуемые модератору, сейчас точно так же видны всем.

Comment: @PavelMayorov модератор может забанить только "в довесок" к личному сообщению, на которое всегда можно ответить.