# Русское сообщество. Бессмыcленное и беспощадное

Tags: предложение, вопросы, stackoverflow

## Бессмыcленный и беспощадный русскоязычный stackoverflow

Может я чего-то не понимаю, может вы мне объясните суть и логику, но зачем сообщество минусует, в принципе, неплохие вопросы и неплохие ответы?

## О чём речь?

Очень часто люди минусуют вопросы с ответами, которые были даны автором (видимо, из ревности, что автор сам ответил, и не дал ответить другим), также часто люди минусуют вопросы, которые считают очевидными (но почему-то забывают о новичках, которые, возможно, ищут решение этой проблемы).

## Сообщество — это база знаний или место для оценок, основанных на личностных предпочтениях?

Когда мы рационально будем оценивать вопросы и ответы? Когда прекратим давать оценку, основанную на том, нравится ли нам лично вопрос/ответ или нет и будем давать оценку, основанную на том, несёт ли в себе сообщение пользу для сообщества, и в первую очередь для новичков?

Посмотрите на заморский [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/). Там люди ставят плюсы, добавляют сообщения в избранное, а ответы, на которые ответил сам автор имеют по 200-1200+ плюсов. Я дал там всего 3 ответа и задал один вопрос и ни разу не получил отрицательный голос. Хотя ответы там я давал примерно такие же, как и тут.

В общем, как говорил Кот Леопольд: "Ребята, давайте жить дружно?". И помимо этого, давайте развивать наше сообщество, а не отбивать это желание.

## Конкретика, как просили

Недавно я задал [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/653634/python-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9). Вполне неплохой, и для новичков информативный на мой взгляд. Я понимаю, что `list()` в Python может хранить всё, что угодно (причём не обязательно одного типа). Тем не менее, мне показалось, что для хранения класса необходимо нечто большее, чем список. Но добравшись до редактора я переписал класс и проверил подойдёт ли список для этой цели. Убедившись в этом, я начал писать ответ на свой вопрос, во время чего получил минус к вопросу.

Comment: Больше конкретики, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вот как раз на английском SO минусы и голоса за закрытие сыпятся как из ведра. Поэтому я там не особо появляюсь и набрал только 4К, а тут в 10 раз больше.

Comment: @PavelMayorov добавил

Comment: на мой взгляд, ваш вопрос из разряда "а дайте мне плюсов". Держите - мне не жалко ;)

Comment: Весь сыр-бор из-за одного единственного минуса?

Comment: @FoggyFinder это даже не совсем вопрос, а скорее побуждение к тому, чтобы оценивать вопросы и ответы рационально, а не с точки зрения "Да это знает любой программист, что за тупой вопрос/ответ?! Минус!"

Comment: @alexolut прочтите комментарий выше

Comment: Прочел. Но это всё равно не меняет сути. Минусующий, как и плюсующий не обязан отчитываться о причине своего голоса. Один голос - это не показатель всего сообщества. Хотя безусловно минусы вряд ли будут приятны автору сообщения.

Comment: @alexolut я не спорю, что голосующие не должны отчитываться о причине своего голоса. Я к тому, что хотелось бы, чтобы в причинах ставить минус не было **ревности**, **предвзятого отношения** и **размышлений вида: "Это знают все, зачем это писать?!"**

Comment: @KitScribe а откуда Вы знаете о причине минуса, если минусатор об этом ничего не сказал?

Comment: @alexolut я стараюсь смотреть на вещи отстранённо и оценивать их объективно, без каких-либо привязанностей и паттернов мышления. И, как я вижу, данный вопрос не является плохим, и если он не является интересным лично для кого-либо, можно просто проигнорировать его, а не ставить минус лишь потому, что проблема вопроса не является интересной/решение или суть известна.

Comment: Не минусовал, но на мой взгляд в вопросе маловато Питона и собственно описания вопроса для Питона. Также, вопрос про создание или сохранение? *это уже в режиме поиска возможных причин минуса*

Comment: @KitScribe в чем цель этого обсужения на мете? узнать причину минуса? или выплеснуть злось в сторону всего русскоязычного community?

Comment: @PashaPash цели 2: `1) побудить всех голосовать объективно`, `2) выяснить причину минуса`

Comment: Призыв хороший, но он из разряда "давайте писать код без багов". Пока есть инструмент, который можно использовать на свое усмотрение, кто-то будет его использовать его на свое усмотрение.

Comment: @KitScribe (1). Минусы - это субъективный механизм. У минуса по определению не может быть полностью объективных причин. Как и у плюса - в админке иногда проскакивает комбинация "участник поставил ответу плюс и тут же выставил на нем тревогу низкого качества/не является ответом". (2) минусанувший с некоторой вероятностью не посещает мету :)

Comment: @KitScribe, минусуют (и плюсуют) конкретные люди, которые вполне вероятно  спрашивают-отвечают  тут просто в свое удовльствие и при этом вообще не думают ни о каком комьюнити.

Comment: @KitScribe, а чего вы вообще хотели от нас, кто в [Глобальном индексе миролюбия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81_%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%8F) занимает 151 (из 163) место?

Comment: Предлагаю всем ознакомиться

Comment: @Qwertiy это может быть проблемой больших чисел.. нас тут несколько тысяч.. там около 15 миллионов пользователей. Да и еще проблема языка.. Меня _некоторые_ минусуют больше здесь, привязываясь к  словам, например, проблем с английской терминологией нет. 4к - это неплохо, это верхние 2% пользователей по репутации :P

Comment: Добавлен ответ.

Answer (score -14, accepted):

Здравствуйте **Kit Scribe**!

Очень правильно что вы здесь подняли эту тему. Я предлагаю вам воспользоваться поиском, запрос типа "За что меня минусуют", вы поймете что здесь это неоднократно поднималось, и увидите чем все это заканчивалось.

Еще посмотрите недавнюю тему [**Шуточные вопросы**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5048/%D0%A8%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B), те вопросы что там обсуждались были на основном сайте примерно неделю, один из них пока был на основном сайте, получил примерно 20 плюсов. Посмотрите за что здесь порой плюсуют, и возможно у вас не останется вопроса, почему здесь порой минусуют не оставляя комментариев.

Также посмотрите мой вопрос на мете [**Ссылка**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4995/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2). Кратко, я попытался удалить свой заминусованный и закрытый вопрос, но мне не дали этого сделать, можно было только отредактировать. После того как я улучшил и отредактировал его, все равно находились люди которые ставили минус, при этом комментарий оставил только один человек. Задача, найти логику действий этих людей.

---

> Бессмыленный и беспощадный русскоязычный stackoverflow

Это не сообщество, а небольшая группа лиц, возможно весьма немногочисленная. На мой взгляд, все происходящее возможно только с попустительства модераторов, поэтому большая часть вины ложится на них.

Я предлагаю пользователям чаще создавать темы наподобие этой, так возможно ситуация изменится. Данный ресурс просматривает огромное кол-во людей, но проявляют активность лишь немногие, этим и пользуются минусующие. Пусть пользователи несогласные с подобным поведением проявляют больше активности, также стоит чаще спрашивать у модераторов и фиксировать их бездействие.

Comment: А причём здесь попустительство, простите? Каждый участник имеет право минусовать всё, что ему кажется плохим вопросом/ответом. И не должен ни перед кем держать ответ за это.

Comment: Что вы предлагаете по существу? Выгнать этих "безалаберных модераторов" и поставить вас? Вы справитесь? Создавать темы наподобие этой по каждому минусу - бесполезно.

Comment: `Посмотрите за что здесь порой плюсуют, и возможно у вас не останется вопроса, почему здесь порой минусуют не оставляя комментариев` — во-первых, те вопросы были *тематическими (первоапрельскими)*. Во-вторых, **перенос на Мету откатил всю репутацию, начисленную за эти плюсы**. К примеру, у Юрия нет ни одного балла за его вопрос про пояс Бэтмена (см. [страницу изменения его репутации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/20458/yuri?tab=reputation), точнее, графу «1 апр»).

Comment: Я неслучайно указал на поиск, таких тем немало, а ведь создают подобные темы лишь малое число людей, большинство предполагаю говоря "ай да ладно" оставляет. Мое предложение, перестать свое собственное мнение распространять на все сообщество и начать считаться с мнением других пользователей. Очевидно для всех, что не минусы всех смущают, а минусы без каких-либо комментариев. Нужно создать такую атмосферу в сообществе, где оставление комментария проголосовавшего всячески поддерживается и приветствуется. Но сообщения как здесь у @VladD действуют наоборот.

Comment: Перестаньте минусовать подобные вопросы. Человек потратил на вопрос время и силы, он посчитал это важным, он пытается понять логику действий и разобраться. Кому все равно, здесь на мете не пишет. Если человеку не все равно, он пришел по адресу, он может здесь высказать свое мнение/пожелания/задать вопрос, своими минусами вы отпугиваете человека от всего этого. Возможно заголовок к данной теме выбран не самый лучший, но нужно быть терпимее и стараться видеть суть вопроса(посыл автора).

Comment: Вот пример для вас появился [**ссылка**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/653520/234502) Возможно не авторы вопросов(как здесь) виноваты и заслуживают минуса, а возможно мы просто научимся доброжелательно относиться друг к другу, научимся разговаривать друг с другом, и тогда возможно проблемы решатся. Не нужно много обсуждений, а просто - **Поставил минус, напиши за что и почему**.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov: Мы обсуждали это на Мете раньше. Я лично за то, чтобы вместе с минусом появлялся и объясняющий комментарий, и стараюсь так и делать. Но мы не имеем права **требовать** этого от остальных по многим причинам (например, это раскроет анонимность минусов). Если вы сумеете **убедить** остальных — будет отлично. Но убедить большое сообщество нахрапом не получится, вы добьётесь лишь противоположного эффекта. У меня, например, вовсе не получилось.

Comment: Вы меня конечно простите но Ваш ответ вызывает у меня злость, попробую объяснить почему: что в предыдущей теме что в текущей Вы предстаете в образе *д'Артаньяна*. С порога не разобравшись Вы начинаете вешать *ярлыки*, *учить жизни*.

Comment: Эй-эй, что за голос за удаление? Даже такой ответ имеет право на жизнь на Мете!

Comment: @PavelMayorov а на смерть он права не имеет что ли?

Comment: @alexolut обратите внимание - у ответа три плюса. Это значит, что как минимум три участника разделяют мнение автора ответа. Если ответ удалить - в лучшем случае появится такой же, с другим авторством. В худшем - будут сказки рассказывать про самодуров на Мете, которые цензуру устроили.

Comment: @PavelMayorov право голосовать за удаление ровно такое же как право ставить минус. Хотя и требует чуть большей репутации.

Comment: @alexolut соглашусь с PavelMayorov. удаление данного ответа, превратят голословные обвинения тс о *самодурстве* в подтвержденный факт

Comment: @Bald голосование - это не самодурство. Самодурством будет удаление с помощью модераторов.

Comment: @alexolut пожалуйста, изучите список своих привилегий. Особенно внимательно посмотрите в каком разделе относится привилегия голосования за удаление.

Comment: @alexolut в какой то мере все участники данного сообщества являются *модераторами*, и Вы и я это знаем. взгляд со стороны: удаление неугодного поста на мете где можно открыто высказывать свои предложения будет оценен как *самодурство* группы лиц действующей в своих интересах

Comment: @PavelMayorov не понимаю, что Вы этим хотите сказать.

Comment: @Bald так увеличение привилегий по мере роста репутации - принятый здесь подход. Чтобы иметь больше прав, надо больше вложиться в сайт. Вы же сами сказали про д'Артаньяна.

Comment: @alexolut я высказал свою позицию и подкрепил ее минусом, но удаление ответа на мете это лишнее.

Comment: @Bald да почему лишнее то? Есть правила, есть привилегии. Устоявшаяся система, которая работает на сайтах SE. Кто-то голосует за удаление, кто-то потом так же может голосовать за восстановление. Бесследно же оно не исчезает в любом случае. Гармония.

Comment: @alexolut я могу понять удаление ответа на основном сайте, но на мете где каждый может высказать свою точку зрения по тому или иному вопросу связанному с работой сайта/сообщества. удаление выглядит как попытка *заткнуть рот*.

Comment: @Bald Да, на Мете хотелось бы кое-что исправить: [раз](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4112/176217), [два](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3804/176217) и [три](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4171/176217). Но пока, что есть, то есть.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57474/discussion-between-pashapash-and-alexandr-kazakov).

Answer (score 19):

### Поехали по порядку:

> зачем сообщество минусует, в принципе, неплохие вопросы и неплохие ответы?

Потому что им они кажутся плохими. Вот и всё. Других причин не нужно.

Это такой способ выражения мнения сообщества, всем дают голосовалку, а каждый распоряжается с ней как хочет. Единственное, в чем система мешает, это в направленных накрутках репутации отдельным участникам. Заподозрив такое явление, система отменяет подозрительные голоса, но других санкций не накладывает.

Так что можно считать, что
**голосовать абсолютно за всё абсолютно как угодно совершенно безопасно**.

В чате временами возмущения на то, что плюсы прилетают на совершенно очевидный трэш. Так что система не идеальна с обеих сторон: бывают ложные срабатывания и ложные несрабатывания. Но их статистически немного.

> Очень часто люди минусуют вопросы с ответами, которые были даны автором (видимо, из ревности, что автор сам ответил, и не дал ответить другим)

Нет, вряд ли причина в этом. Причина совершенно надуманная. То, что ответ принят, не мешает оставлять новые ответы. +15 за принятие собственного ответа автор тоже не получит. Более того, автор может одуматься и принять другой ответ, если он оказался полезнее, пусть и несколько запоздал (неоднократно в такую ситуацию попадал). На SO и ru.SO полно вопросов, у которых принятые ответы по голосам далеко не первые.

**"Не даёт ответить другим" только закрытие.**

Так что это точно ерунда, но от случая к случаю ерунда разных видов.

> также часто люди минусуют вопросы, которые считают очевидными (но почему-то забывают о новичках, которые, возможно, ищут решение этой проблемы).

И имеют на то право, см. выше. И более того, это употребление минусов по их прямому назначению. Подсказка у минусующей стрелочки содержит "вопрос не отражает стремления разобраться".

Но минусы не отменяют возможности ответить на вопрос, см. выше. Если оставить к такому вопросу **хороший ответ**, вам прилетят плюсы. А в ряде случаев можно причесать вопрос путём редактирования, и в него тоже прилетят плюсы, хоть и автору вопроса.

> Сообщество — это база знаний или место для оценок, основанных на личностных предпочтениях?

База знаний. Оценки сбоку и слабо влияют на всё остальное, служат больше для обратной связи авторам сообщений и не влияют на пригодность системы на роль базы знаний. Плюсы в 5 раз влиятельнее минусов, поэтому даже за полный трэш по показателю репутации можно остаться в плюсе.

> Когда мы рационально будем оценивать вопросы и ответы? Когда прекратим давать оценку, основанную на том, нравится ли нам лично вопрос/ответ или нет и будем давать оценку, основанную на том, несёт ли в себе сообщение пользу для сообщества, и в первую очередь для новичков?

Я выше уже ответил, но приведу очень краткую выжимку, буквально в одно слово, отвечающую на все эти вопросы:

#### Ни-ког-да.

Потому что голосующие различаются во мнениях по поводу полезности тех или иных вопросов и ответов. А поскольку вопросы ещё и подписаны, нередки случаи, когда голоса отдаются из неприязни (или, реже, симпатии) к автору. Это они зря. Но влияние этого фактора пренебрежимо мало.

Просто не надо считать, что мнение каждого голосующего совпадает с мнением сообщества. Это может быть неправдой, а в ряде случаев это даже **чаще** неправда: взять хотя бы проблему "работы за автора". Мы вроде бы договорились, что голосовать надо **за вопрос, а не за за намерения автора**. Что вопрос вида "работа за автора" допустим и как причина закрытия это несостоятельно; а что вопрос может быть плох по другим причинам, это уже совсем другая история.

> Посмотрите на заморский SO.

Давайте! Я оттуда начал в своё время. [6к репы там](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2076787/d-side) не дадут соврать.

> Я дал там всего 3 ответа и задал один вопрос и ни разу не получил отрицательный голос.

Ага, на 4 сообщениях у вас два плюса и ни одного минуса. Это при том, что там на порядок больше народу. Но и больше сообщений, поэтому каждое конкретное сообщение быстро "проваливается" вниз.

У вас на SO голоса в пределах вышеописанной погрешности и не дают возможности делать какие бы там ни было выводы.

Answer (score 8):

Дабы текущий вопрос на Мете не [удалился из-за минусов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4112/176217) - отвечу. Один единственный минус (а пусть даже и несколько) не является показателем сообщества в целом. Здесь я даже не буду вдаваться в какой-либо разбор качества и полезности вопроса, т.к. это совершенно не важно.

Голосующий не обязан отчитываться о причине своего голоса. Как "против", так и "за". Рекомендации о том когда и как следует голосовать могут быть почерпнуты из вопроса [Когда следует голосовать?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4048/176217). Как мне кажется, там всё расписано довольно подробно.

P.S. Сомнительно надеяться на поддержку (голосование "за") по вопросу, когда его заголовок оскорбителен для сообщества. Тем не менее, кто-то поставил плюс, и он в своём праве. Ситуация ровно такая же как для Вашего вопроса по Python, хотя и с обратным знаком.